# Match text from workbook 1 column A and workbook 2 column A and return value from column B in Workbook 2

Tags: excel, macros, excel-formula, vba

I have a workbook 1 with email addresses in column A. I also have a workbook 2 with addresses in column G.

In workbook 1 column B I am trying to write a formula that will match the email addresses from workbook 1 Column A and workbook 2 column G. Once a match is found using the formula, I want the rest of the formula to copy the information from column E from workbook 2.

This is the formula I am using: =INDEX([International Devices (3) 3.10 v3.xlxs]Australia!$G$2:$G$4, MATCH(International Good and BES Users.xlsx]Australia!$A$2, [International Devices (3) 3.10 v3.xlsx]Australia!$E$2:$E$4,0),1)

I am receiving an error and unable to make it work. Am I on the right track, is there anything I can change to the formula to make it work.

**Error**

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding but let me unpack this a little bit:

Are you trying to INDEX MATCH more than one address in workbook 1? If so, you have set the MATCH value as $A$2, meaning it will not change during an autofill.

Also, it sounds like you're creating the formula inside of "International Good and BES Users.xlsx". If so, trying writing "...Match(A2,..." instead of spelling out the current workbook and sheet you're already in.

The final formula would look like

"=INDEX([International Devices (3) 3.10 v3.xlxs]Australia!$G$2:$G$4, MATCH(A2, [International Devices (3) 3.10 v3.xlsx]Australia!$E$2:$E$4,0),1)"

---

Answer #2: "=INDEX([International Devices (3) 3.10 v3.xlsx]Australia!$E$2:$E$4, MATCH(A2,[International Devices (3) 3.10 v3.xlxs]Australia!$G$2:$G$4,0),1)"

Comment: Yes, you are correct on your deduction. I updated my formula I keep receiving the same error I posted on the summary. That didn't work. Any guidance would be great. :)

Comment: After re-reading the question I think that you've mixed up which range you want to return a value FROM vs. which one you want to match. Also, do you only have 3 addresses that you're checking (A2-A4) or more?

Comment: I found out what the issue was. I will copy and paste the working formula below. It appears that when the formula was trying to find the other workbook, for some reason wouldn't read with numbers or spaces in them.

Comment: My workbook wasn't read by the formula. Had to remove all the spaces and numbers, very odd. The new formula works now but it auto mapped the folder structure as well, is that normal?=INDEX('C:\Users\sgatica\Documents\PM00045406\BES, GOOD and Mobileiron Inventory\Countries Migrated to MI\March\International Good and BES users\[InternationalDevicesTest.xlsx]Australia'!$E$2:$E$4,MATCH(A3:A122,'C:\Users\sgatica\Documents\PM00045406\BES, GOOD and Mobileiron Inventory\Countries Migrated to MI\March\International Good and BES users\[InternationalDevicesTest.xlsx]Australia'!$G$2:$G$4,0),1)

Comment: I have referenced external workbooks before and while they are open it is not that crazy but when the source is closed you'll get that result: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f